# Convert varchar to a double in DataSet TableAdapter Fill

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, dataset, tableadapter

In SQL Server 2008, I have a strongly typed data set with a table:

```
TABLE
 ID (Guid)
 Value (varchar(50))
```

This this table, *Value* actually represents an encrypted value on the database, which becomes decrypted after reading from this table on my server.

In Visual Studio; I have a Dataset with my table, which looks like:

```
TABLE
 ID (Guid)
 Value (float)
```

I want to know if there is a way, in a DataSet, to call my decryption methods on *Value* when I am calling my **Fill** Query on the TableAdapter for this Table.

Is there anyway to extend the DataSet XSD to support this sort of *data massaging* when reading data?

In addition to this, is there a way when inserting/updating records in this table to write strings to encrypted values?

NOTE:
All Encrypt/Decryption code is being performed on the client to the database, **not** on the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fill() method is going to execute whatever SQL is in the SelectCommand property of the DataAdapter.  It's certainly possible to customize the SQL to "massage" data as it comes in.

Your issue is made more complex by the need to execute some .NET decryption.  If you really want to do this and it is of high value to you, you could install a .NET assembly in the SQL Server database.  Once this was done, you should be able to specify a custom SelectCommand that calls the code in your ,NET assembly to decrypt the data at select-time.

But that seems like an awful lot of work for very little reward.  It's probably easier and more efficient to simply post-process the dataset and decrypt there. :)

Comment: Trying to jam in this logic into the DataAdapter just wasn't working.  I am trying a different approach now.  Thanks for your response!